# How do I configure the Unreal Engine Localization Dashboard to gather String Tables that loaded from c++?

Tags: c++, localization, unreal-engine5, string-table

When I try with (Unreal Engine 5) Localization Dashboard to gather text,
String Tables that loaded from c++ are excluded...

Other String Tables that created from Editor as assets are being gathered well.

---

First, I followed this blog : https://benui.ca/unreal/stringtable-cpp/

Then, it was possible to access to the loaded String Tables from "Make Literal Text" blueprint node.

But when I tried to "Gather Text" on "Localization Dashboard", it didn't gather any text in the String Tables above.

Comment: Try posting this question in [UE forums](https://forums.unrealengine.com/) as well.

Comment: Many thanks!
My problem was solved :D

https://forums.unrealengine.com/t/localization-dont-work-on-dynamic-string-table-loaded-from-csv/403243

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After making sure that the source file is being gathered, my problem was solved.

UE forum worked for me :D

https://forums.unrealengine.com/t/localization-dont-work-on-dynamic-string-table-loaded-from-csv/403243